# How can I append index before values in pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,5,7,9],'col2':['abc','defg','fghei','swe']})
df.index = ['1234','1235','1236','1237']

df

       col1  col2
1234    1   abc
1235    5   defg
1236    7   fghei
1237    9   swe
```

Now I want to append index before each value of `col2`, but the length of the column value should not be more than 6. If it is more than 7, then it should strip the index.

Required output:

```
    col1    col2
1234    1   1234abc
1235    5   123defg
1236    7   12fghei
1237    9   1234swe
```

What I tried:

```
df['col2_len'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
df['idx'] = df.index

df['idx_len'] = df['idx'].apply(lambda x: len(x))

df['col2'] = df['idx'] + df['col2']
print(df)
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: x[0:7])
df.drop(['col2_len','idx','idx_len'],1)
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
    col1    col2
1234    1   1234abc
1235    5   1235def
1236    7   1236fgh
1237    9   1237swe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list comprehension`:

```
df['col2'] = [x[: 7-len(y)] + y for x, y in zip(df.index, df['col2'])]
print (df)
      col1     col2
1234     1  1234abc
1235     5  123defg
1236     7  12fghei
1237     9  1237swe
```

**Explanation**:

1. First `zip` `index` and columns values for `tuples`
2. Loop in list comprehension
3. For each value `y` for `column` get length by `len`
4. Subtract expected length - `7` for slicing value `x` (`index`)
5. Last add value `y`

Comment: @Sociopath27 - Working for it ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation.

Comment: @jezrael : Awesome answer as always. How do you think about this approach as keeping the original data is always a good idea:           df.reset_index(inplace = True)
df['combined']=df['index'].astype(str)+df['col2']

Comment: @anky_91 - Thank you. There is problem you need dynamic for each value indexing by length, so vectorizing here is not posible use :(

Comment: Okay, nice. Thanks a lot. :)